# Xcode Cordova project error on config.xml

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

When building my Cordova project on XCode, the following runtime exception is shown when the app starts on the simulator

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception
 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'ERROR: config.xml does not exist. 
Please run cordova-ios/bin/cordova_plist_to_config_xml path/to/project.'
```

It then shows the uncaught exception at this line in main.m:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
```

Where is this located and how to run this command?

Comment: Root folder of cordova and one more inside iOS project

Comment: What is exactly the command? It gives `cordova_plist_path_to_config_xml: No such file or directory`

Comment: I am getting this issue after renaming the product name in the project.